# general question about links

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I feel i little bit stupid to ask this, but... :)

If i'm visitor of some website (let's say "www.site.com"), and i'm currently on this page "www.site.com/pageX" and I open that page's source, i'll find some "`<A>`" tags. If those tags have hrefs like this href="/pageY/.content.html" how can I tell (without clicking that link, or looking at links full address) if link points to "www.site.com/pageY/content.html" OR "www.site.com/pageX/PageY/content.html"?

I hope this question is not too confusing :)

Comment: ... mouse over the links and see what's in the status bar?

Comment: I'm guessing SO is parsing out the code where you say "I'll find some "" tags." Put that in backticks, or select it and click the code button in the editor.

Comment: @vector: "without clicking that link, or looking at links full address". The question's confusing even without stripped code; I'm guessing OP is trying to reproduce something programmaticly (ergo the quoted instruction). (Edit: Or maybe I'm completely wrong and OP is just trying to figure out what the first slash in a filename means...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the URL starts with a slash / then it starts from the root of the site. So href="/pageY/content.html" will point to www.site.com/pageY/content.html. While href="pageY/content.html" points to the current location so: www.site.com/pageX/pageY/content.html.

Comment: This is only correct when the site does not use a `<base href="...">`

Comment: YES! That's exactly what i wanted to ask! I HAD NO IDEA about <base href> tag :) Now it's much clearer :)

Comment: @Dutchie432 Thanks. That's right. So the answer should read "starts from the base url of the site".

Answer (score 0):

If you see `<a href="">Text of link</a>` then that link links to the current page with the same URL. You also see that often in forms to post the POST-data to the same URL. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can tell because that link starts with a `/` which means it will be relative to the site root.

You can read more about this here: http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php#root

Comment: ..relative to the site root, or the `<base href="...">`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question correctly, but will try to explain.

There are relative and absolute URL's. Relative URL's look like `content.html` or `./content.html`. Absolute URL's start with an `/`, like `/pageX/content.html`.

Relative URL's will be appended to the base href, which is the directory you're in (`www.site.com/pageX` for `www.site.com/pageX/index.html`). The base href can be changed with the `<base/>` element. Visiting `content.html` when you're on `www.site.com/pageX` would lead you to `www.site.com/pageX/content.html`.

Absolute URL's will always append the URL to the domain. Visiting `/content.html` when you're on `www.site.com/pageX` would lead you to `www.site.com/content.html`.

Don't know if that answered your question though.